# Django update model with original data

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have this modelform, where Invoice_number is being auto generated on save.

My problem: when I update any field in this model form a new invoice number is being generated.

Is there any way I can update the form and keep the original invoice number unchanged!!

```
class sale(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)
    contact = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50,null=True)
    Delivery_Date = models.DateField(null=True)
    Delivery_time = models.CharField(max_length=80,null=True)
    service = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True)
    Invoice_number = models.CharField(max_length=12,blank=True,unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.service == 'Furniture':
            x=randint(99,99999)
            self.Invoice_number = str('Fur') + str(x)
        elif self.service == 'Auto':
            x=randint(99,99999)
            self.Invoice_number = str('Auto') + str(x)
        elif self.service == 'Groceries':
            x=randint(99,99999)
            self.Invoice_number = str('Gro') + str(x)
        super(bookings_modelform,self).save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check in model's `save` method if object new, using `self.pk` and generate invoice number only in this case:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.pk is None:
        if self.service == 'Furniture':
            x=randint(99,99999)
            self.Invoice_number = str('Fur') + str(x)
        elif self.service == 'Auto':
            x=randint(99,99999)
            self.Invoice_number = str('Auto') + str(x)
        elif self.service == 'Groceries':
            x=randint(99,99999)
            self.Invoice_number = str('Gro') + str(x)
    super(bookings_modelform,self).save()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the instance already has an invoice number, e.g.:

```
...
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.Invoice_number:
        if self.service == 'Furniture':
            x=randint(99,99999)
            self.Invoice_number = str('Fur') + str(x)
            ...
```

That being said, your method is prone to errors as once in a while you will end up with clashing invoice numbers (because of the nature of random numbers) and your `save()` will fail, losing the invoice. I suggest you to first check if that invoice number is used before.

You are also calling the wrong `super` (it should be the superclass of `sale`, not `bookings_modelform`), i.e.:

```
super(sale, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you very much